# Is it possible to use two email for smtp in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, smtp, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to use two email for smtp in wordpress?
i want to use different email id for order related emails.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not within the scope of questions appropriate for Stack Overflow, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [wordpress.se].

Comment: yes use's different email

Answer (score 0):

Go to woocommerce menu and look for email tab. You can setup email addresses there as per your requirement. Hope this helps.